# Problem while making assembly bootloader, that writes all the background colors to the video memory

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, fasm

I would like to make a simple bootloader, that writes all the background colors to next lines on the screen.
**The problem** is, that it only changes the color of the first line to black and the second line to blue, while it **should display all 16 colors**. I think, that there is **something wrong with *loop1:***, but I don't know what.
Useful informations:

- I am writing directly to the text video memory, starting from address 0xb8000, using method described in [this forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681795/how-to-write-to-screen-with-video-memory-address-0xb8000-from-real-mode).
- I am using *flat assembler 1.73.27 for Windows* (fasm assembler).
- I am testing my program on real computer (booting from usb), not an emulator.
- I am not including any photos, because of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557).

My code (fasm assembly):

```
format binary
use16
org 0x7c00
mov ax,0xb800
mov es,ax
mov bx,0
mov al,0
mov ah,0x0f
mov cx,160
loop1:
call procedure1
add ax,0x1000
add cx,160
cmp ah,0xff
jl loop1
call procedure1
mov cx,4000
mov ah,0x0f
call procedure1
jmp $
procedure1:
mov word [es:bx],ax
add bx,2
cmp bx,cx
jl procedure1
ret
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: In this particular case, I see no problem in including a photo of the resulting output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are leaving `loop1` when `ah` is not **less** than `0xff` anymore.
The term *less/greater* is used in x86 assembly when signed numbers are compared.
Number `0xff` treated as signed 8bit integer has the value `-1` and `ah` as signed byte (-128..+127), starts at `0x0f + 0x10 = 0x1f`.  And `31 < -1` is false on the first iteration, so `loop1` is abandoned after the first `call procedure1`.

When comparing unsigned numbers we use term *below/above*.
Instead of `jl loop1` use `jb loop1`. Similary in `procedure1:` replace `jl procedure1` with `jb procedure1`.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc)

Comment: Number `0xFF` is actually minus one, not minus 128.

Comment: Thanks, now the loop is working, but I get the same 8 colors twice instead of all 16 bios colors, but as I read in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_color_attributes), there are only 8 background colors with an exception to have 16 colors, of turning off the "blinking attribute", but as I'm not using any interrupts now, I will not change that.

Comment: @ecm Ooops, mea culpa. But the conclusion is still valid.
@Julian I think using BIOS service is harmless. Just do  `MOV AX,0x1003` and `INT 0x10`  somewhere in the beginning, and you'll see the bright colors.

Comment: It's a good idea not to leave confusing mis-statements in your answers, regardless of the conclusion.  I fixed that 0xff = -1 for you.

Comment: @vitsoft You also need to add `mov bx,0` before `int 0x10` (to set BH and BL to 0), See [_Ralf Brown's Interrupt List_ Int 10/AX=1003h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0117.htm).