# Is it possible to write multiple characters in C++ Assembly with no stdlib?

Tags: c++, operating-system

I am developing a operating system, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwPjvJ9ulSc&list=PLm3B56ql_akNcvH8vvJRYOc7TbYhRs19M&index=1), and I'm on [part 7 (chapter 7)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpFUzjYehxs&list=PLm3B56ql_akNcvH8vvJRYOc7TbYhRs19M&index=7), and he shows how to print a character to the screen, but I want to print multiple characters but it just overwrites the previous character. Here is my code

```cpp
extern "C" void main() {
    // printf("Hello, World!");
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'H';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'e';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'l';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'l';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'o';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = ',';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = ' ';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'W';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'o';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'r';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'l';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = 'd';
    *(char *)0xb8000 = '!';
    return;
}
```

Comment: Try writing successive characters to successive memory locations.

Comment: All the addresses are the same.. hmm. (Also, there is no assembly here, nor does C++ define assembly.)

Comment: Will incrementing the address every time work? I think that might cause memory corruption and possibly overflows.

Comment: Also, @user2864740, the OS I am working with IS made in assembly

Comment: “..memory corruption..”, possibly. However the current *replace the same character in memory* clearly is **not** a usable solution for the task.

Comment: (The OS being written in assembly is irrelevant to C++.)

Comment: And here you’d want to look at *video memory* (which is how even a single character is displayed). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972051/in-c-how-do-i-write-to-a-particular-memory-location-e-g-video-memory-b800-in

Comment: What exactly is _video memory_?

Comment: Gameshow host: Sorry, we were looking for “What is 0xb8000?” (The answer is “video memory”, however that has been arrange to “display a character”. The should be explained in the resource showing usage of such.)

Comment: Also I'm using protected mode since real mode C++ is a pain

Comment: Various resources explaining some usages of said memory region (depends on hardware, etc.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681795/how-to-write-to-screen-with-video-memory-address-0xb8000-from-real-mode , https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen , http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/the-world-of-protected-mode

Comment: I'm trying it, OK?

Comment: that address is valid only in plain mode with IBM PC/XT compatible hardware.. I have no idea what even that is working with, looks like primitive version of DOS.. OpenDOS?

Comment: I'm working with QEMU

Comment: @user2864740 Outputs [this garbage](https://qardruss.api-minecraft.net/sq35XyF8)

Comment: That’s what you told it to output. Hint: every other byte is being used for color information. Now please go **read** some resources on how to access *this particular* memory layout correctly. Reiteration of a provided a link: https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen to the format it appears to be using..

Comment: Oh I tried the OSDev link, @user2864740, and their print function worked!

Comment: what architecture? as I said  trying t write into  0xb8000 is IBM PC/XT thing (essentially the very first x86  PC that ever existed, 42 years ago). No color, single byte per character representation of screen. The correct mode should be set beforehand (as you're not setting it in your program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2864740 sent me [a link](https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen) that helped me fix it, as it turns out, every 2nd character written to `0xB8000` is a color.
So if you wanted to print `Hello!`, I'm pretty sure you would do

```cpp
*(char*)0xB8000 = "H";
*(char*)0xB8001 = 15;
*(char*)0xB8002 = "e";
*(char*)0xB8003 = 15;
*(char*)0xB8004 = "l";
*(char*)0xB8005 = 15;
*(char*)0xB8006 = "l";
*(char*)0xB8007 = 15;
*(char*)0xB8008 = "o";
*(char*)0xB8008 = 15;
*(char*)0xB8009 = "!";
*(char*)0xB800a = 15;
```

**(untested)**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write multiple characters in C++ Assembly with no stdlib?

There is no standard way to write one or more characters in C++ other than using the standard library.

The system (operating system / CPU architecture) may have ways, but that depends on which OS / CPU you are using. See their documentation.

There is no one assembly language; each CPU architecture has their own language, and compilers have their own syntax.